# Header Text over Image

Tags: html, image, css

I want my Header text (Events, Blog, About) to LAY ON TOP OF the "Images/Damask.png" image.  Instead the image is displayed at the very top of the header with the text BELOW the image.

```
<header>

    <header>
    <img src="Images/Damask.png" width="100%" border="0" height="200" class="header">
        <a href="index.html" id= "logo">![enter image description here][1]
            <h1>J Barnes Events</h1>
            <h2>Indianapolis's Finest<h2>   
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of separately adding an image, you can simply add the following CSS to your stylesheet and that would achieve what you're trying to do:

```
header {
     background-image: url('Images/Damask.png');
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to put the url in quotes.

Comment: Didn't work :(  It completely deleted the image from the page.  What happened????

Comment: Please share the link to your website.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9gr0emex/3/) for you, I've used the same HTML which you've posted in your question above.You can see how I've assigned a background image to the `header` tag using CSS.

Comment: You only need to quote the URL if you have special characters, which there are none in this example and best avoided anyway. The _relative_ URL in an external CSS file is unlikely to be the same as the _relative_ URL in the HTML file. Relative paths in the CSS file are relative to the CSS file, not the HTML file.