# Text Lay Over Header Image

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML, but can't seem to get the text to LAY OVER the image.  I'd like the h1, h2, and ul li tags to LAY OVER the image.

I know I can put the image in CSS, I just need to know how to edit the CSS (or HTML?) so the text will LAY OVER the image.

```
<header>
<img src="Images/Damask.png" width="100%" border="0" height="200" class="header">
    <a href="index.html" id= "logo">![enter image description here][1]
        <h1>J Barnes Events</h1>
        <h2>Indianapolis's Finest<h2>   
    </a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: If you know how to put the image in CSS (I assume you mean as a `background-image`) then why don't you do that? Then it is easy to lay the text over the image. Or is the image intrinsic to the content (but if you are laying text over it then I would guess not)?

Comment: I did, and the image completely disappeared.

Comment: header {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 30px 0;
 padding: 5px 0 0 0;
 width: 100%;
 border-color: #36546A;
 background-image: url('Images/Damask.png');
}

Comment: Note that the URL in the CSS is relative to the CSS file, not the HTML - so this is unlikely to be the same as your HTML (unless you use absolute or root-relative URLs).

Comment: Even if the image is in a separate "Images" folder?  I'm new to web design, so I'm kind of over my head with this.  What would the code look like? Thanks!

Comment: If your CSS file is "/Styles/default.css" then a relative path in your CSS file, such as `Images/Damask.png`, will refer to "/Styles/Images/Damask.png". Is that correct? You should use root-relative paths (ie. starting with a `/` - relative to the web root) to avoid this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Header Text over Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349049/header-text-over-image)

Answer (score 3):

You can use relative position to img and absolute position to child element which to lay over.
Try like this-

```
<header>
<style type="text/css">
.header{
position:relative;
}
a{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}
.nav{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:100;
}
</style>
</header>
<img src="Images/Damask.png" width="100%" border="0" height="200" class="header"/>
    <a href="index.html" id= "logo">![enter image description here][1]
        <h1>J Barnes Events</h1>
        <h2>Indianapolis's Finest</h2>   
    </a>
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```